# Appending from for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this Python script and instead of hard coding values into it, I am using feedparser to download rss titles and to append it to an array, but I am having trouble.

The current code (which works):

```
for name, date, no in (
        ("Title1", datetime.date(2014,8,9), 3),
        ("Title2", datetime.date(2014,8,3), 23),
        ("Title3", datetime.date(2014,4,6), 51)):
            self.list.append(person(name, date, no))
```

What I am trying to do (and failing):

```
    for post in url.entries:
        name = post.title
        date = datetime.date(2014,2,1) # hardcoded date is fine
        no = 1 # hardcoded number is fine
        self.list.append(person(name, date, no))
```

How do I append the results of the for loop to the person object?

Thanks

Comment: How exactly is the code failing? If an exception occurs, please post the full traceback.

Comment: Hey @LevLevitsky The 2nd code snippet I have published just won't add anything to the list

Comment: What is `url.entries` then? Have you tried printing it?

Comment: Is there a stack trace when you run the failing code?

Comment: Try adding this line before the for loop to see what the length of the entries list is  : print len(url.entries)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that you most likely get `url.entries` of zero length. If there was a problem with the post object you'd get some exception when running the new code snippet.

So try to debug the getting of `url.entries`, I think you'll find that it is empty.